# Formatter Black not working for my VScode Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code, formatter

My black formatter that used to work to format my notebook cells on autosave (after delay) is no longer working since months ago even though autopep8 is working. I use a virtual environment to work with my notebooks. I also installed black there. So here is my user settings:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": null,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}, 
"python.formatting.blackPath": "C:/Users/core i5/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Lib/site-packages/black",
```

The output when I try to format my cells look like this:

```
> "~/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Lib/site-packages/black" --diff --quiet ".\CPE 312\KNN-SVM-NaiveBayes\Hands-on Activity 4.1 K Nearest Neighbors.ipynb.e65891a52a42197e13c75efc5b59ebe7.tmp"
cwd: .
> "~/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Lib/site-packages/black" --version

Formatting with black failed.
You could either install the 'black' formatter, turn it off or use another formatter.
Error: spawn C:/Users/core i5/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Lib/site-packages/black ENOENT
```

Anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am quite new to VScode settings and have just installed black using "pip install black" when I am in the virutal environment. All it says is that "Requirement already satisifed" for all the lines. And when I checked the site-packages where black is installed the folder is already there and that was the path I used for the settings.  My settings also point to the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Black is correctly installed into your virtual environment, and if your VSCode project is pointing to the correct environment, you shouldn't have to provide a path to `black.exe` in the first place. The package provides an entrypoint and should "just work" with the virtual environment activated.

I suggest you remove the `"python.formatting.blackPath"` setting entirely.

If for some reason you want to provide an explicit path to Black, you'll need to change that setting. Don't point to the directory in `Lib/site-packages/`; point to the *binary in `Scripts/`*, which should be something like

```
~/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Scripts/black.exe
```

Comment: Oh wow it worked! I added this `~/Documents/GitHub/DataScience/pyenv/Scripts/black.exe` worked! Do you know what settings to configure when I want the formatter to automatically format on save or on autosave?

Comment: If you open the settings via `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)` you can search and explore through the available settings. Try putting "format" in the search box. If you'd prefer to edit JSON you can still find settings this way: hover over the one you want, click the gear that appears, and then "Copy Setting ID". You might be looking for `editor.formatOnSave`.